# Power BI DAX: Calculate mode based on conditio

Tags: powerbi, dax, frequency

| Name | Day | Sales | "Global" mode | Mode, gruoped on "Name" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Matt | 1 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Matt | 2 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Matt | 3 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Matt | 4 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Matt | 5 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Matt | 6 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Matt | 7 | 95 | 100 | 100 |
| Matt | 8 | 90 | 100 | 100 |
| Andrew | 1 | 99 | 100 | 99 |
| Andrew | 2 | 99 | 100 | 99 |
| Andrew | 3 | 99 | 100 | 99 |
| Andrew | 4 | 99 | 100 | 99 |
| Andrew | 5 | 99 | 100 | 99 |
| Andrew | 6 | 94 | 100 | 99 |
| Andrew | 7 | 94 | 100 | 99 |
| Andrew | 8 | 89 | 100 | 99 |

I want to calculate the mode (most frequent value) of sales, grouped on "Name".

I want to calculate it as a column, as shown in the table.

The mode of all values is calculated like this:

```
"Global" mode = 
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE( Table1, Table1[Sales], "Count", COUNTROWS( Table1 ) )
VAR MostRepeated =
    MAXX( T1, [Count] )
RETURN
    MAXX( T1, IF( [Count] = MostRepeated, Table1[Sales] ) )
```

Source: [Measure to calculate most repeated value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729642/measure-to-calculate-most-repeated-value-in-a-column)

i tried to modify the formula for the global mode, but was unsucsessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to:

```
Mode per Name =
  var perName = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
      ADDCOLUMNS(
        DISTINCT(Table1[Sales]),
        "fq", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1))
      ),
      ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[Name])
    )
  return
    MINX(
      TOPN(1, perName, [fq], DESC),
      [Sales]
    )
```

For what's it worth - Power Query does have a `List.Mode` function and would be a better place to add these columns.